# Difference between torch.sum((x-y)**2) and torch.norm(x-y,p=2)

Tags: python, pytorch

```
def generate_disk(width, height, radius):
    x,y = torch.linspace(-1, 1, width),torch.linspace(-1, 1, height)
    X, Y = torch.meshgrid(x, y)
    distance = torch.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    disk = (distance <= radius).float()
    return disk
```

I'm working with a disk with radius 0.2 of shape (1,50,50) and a disk2 with radius 0.4 of shape (1,50,50). I want to compute the norm 2 of the difference of the disk and the disk2. But the results are `torch.sum((disk-disk2)**2)=224`, `torch.norm(disk-disk2,p=2)=14,966`.

Do you know why those 2 results are differents ?

Comment: Isn't norm usually `(sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2)^(1/2)`? Maybe you forgot the ^(1/2) ?

Comment: Oh yes lol you're right. Totally forgot about that, thank you.

Comment: Haha yes :) Did this solve your problem @Cantor?

Comment: Yes i just forgot the square root. And do you know which one is better if i want to backpropagate (error.backard()) after ?

Comment: Cool, then I think you can mark the answer as accepted. About which one is better: maybe you can test and benchmark both @Cantor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the context, the norm is usually

```
(sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2)^(1/2)
```

Maybe you forgot the exponent `^(1/2)` and this explains your issue.